# When installing wordpress through WP CLI mysite.com/admin not working

Tags: wp-admin, admin, wp-cli

When I am downdloading wordpress and manually installing it, then *mysite.com/admin* working which opens the admin panel. But when I am insatlling *wordpress* using `WP CLI` /admin not redirecting to admin panel.

Can anyone help me to findout the issue.

Using command as below::

```
wp core download --allow-root
wp core config --dbname=wp --dbuser=root --dbpass= --allow-root
wp db create --allow-root
wp core install --url=localhost/rana/wordpress/ --title='wordpress' --admin_user='wordpress' --admin_password='wordpress' --admin_email=admin@localhost.com --allow-root
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress Admin is accessible through the url: *mysite.com/wp-admin/*

The only exception to this is if you have a plugin which explicitly changes this, but most sites will be at */wp-admin/*

Comment: Yes I know that can access through mysite.com/wp-admin/ but it also accessible through mysite.com/admin.